# iPad development: Cannot Find Protocol Declaration

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have declared a protocol, everything seems to work fine, even Xcode auto-complete the name of the protocol if I try to adopt it, but when I compile the project it keeps telling me "Cannot Find Protocol Declaration". It's strange because is the second protocol I adopt in the same class and I dont have any error with the former! Here is the code:

Here I declare the protocol:

```
//  LoginViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol LoginEndDelegate <NSObject>

 -(void)doneLogin;


@end
```

And here I try to adopt it:

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "WebServiceAPI.h"

@protocol SubstitutableDetailViewController
- (void)showRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem;
- (void)invalidateRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem;
@end


@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController   <UISplitViewControllerDelegate,WebServiceAPIDelegate,LoginEndDelegate> {
```

Please help me out guys.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try preprocessing the source file that imports your second code snippet and make sure the declaration for LoginEndDate appears before the interface declaration.  (the product menu has a "Generate Preprocesssed file" item under "Generate Output" on XCode 4).

Most likely you have an import dependency cycle.  `LoginViewController.h` possibly imports something that causes the interface declaration to be imported ahead of the protocol declaration.

Comment: the problem was an import dependency cycle. Thanks for help